# Multiple category Dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to create a category menu like [this](http://www.flipkart.com/combo-samsung-galaxy-s-duos-s7562/p/itmdddbup6fn8mmy?pid=BUNDG7YUAKDVXCGA&ref=2f45ad87-c8e4-43b4-9e91-2bb19ad15837&icmpid=bestsell_hp_mobile_1&otracker=hp_main_mobiles_p_image).

I have created this so far :  http://jsfiddle.net/q5GcD/

The big menu should close only if i take mouse out of bigmenu div.

Also, i am unable to position the big menu correctly so that it overlaps the small menu button.

Html :

```
<div id="mydiv">Menu</div>
<div id="bigmenu">This is big menu</div>
```

Css :

```
#mydiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:50px;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#bigmenu {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:50x;
    height:500px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:orangered;
}
```

script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#bigmenu').css("display","none");
    $('#mydiv').hover(function(){
        $('#bigmenu').css("display","inline");

        },function(){
           $('#bigmenu').css("display","none");
            }

        );

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript, you can do it with CSS only using the `:hover` *dynamic pseudo-class*.

`#bigmenu` should be a child of `#mydiv`, not a sibling, to keep it active until you go out of `#bigmenu` (instead of just out of `#mydiv`).

You don't need absolute position too.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/q5GcD/1/

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">
   Menu
   <div id="bigmenu">
      This is big menu
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mydiv {
    min-height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#mydiv:hover > #bigmenu{
    display: block;
}

#bigmenu {  
    display: none;
    height:500px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:orangered;
}
```

This line:

> #mydiv:hover > #bigmenu{

is telling the browser to apply the rule between the brackets for an element with `id="bigmenu"`, that is child (with `>`, the [Child Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)) of an element with `id="myDiv"`, when you are hovering (mouse on) it.

In the case of a sibling, like in your original HTML code, you should have used `+`, that is the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/q5GcD/3/   ,,  that sample text div will go at the bottom when you hover at menu.. How do i take care of that..

Comment: Then you should use `position: absolute` on `#bigmenu`, and `position: relative` on `#myDiv` to specify that bigmenu is referring in an absolute way to mydiv positions, not to document position: http://jsfiddle.net/q5GcD/4/ (then you can move mydiv wherever you want, and bigmenu will follow it...)

Comment: and adding `top:0;`, now that it is absolute, will set bigmenu at the top overriding the iddiv content (if that is what you want): http://jsfiddle.net/q5GcD/5/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/q5GcD/2/

You have a typo in your css, `50x` instead of `50px`, that takes care of the alignment.

As for JS, use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of hover

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a list menu :)

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=''>Cat drop</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=''>second drop</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

quick CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
  }
ul >li {
    /* top style */
    background:#FF0000;
}
ul>li>ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    background:#00FF00;
}
ul>li:hover>ul{
   display:block;
}
```

with the last selector yo won't need any jQuery or javascript. That's what I think they're using but I could be wrong. You can still use both I think? Not 100% sure on that one.